# In sitefinity, How to prevent appending default Language prefix in page URLs?

Tags: sitefinity-8

In my sitefinity application, I need to remove default language prefix from sitefinity page URLs. Like in my case **ar** from https://www.example.net/ar/individual/products

So I did the following configuration change as mentioned in sitefinity documents:

1- Clicked Administration » Settings » Advanced.

2-In the treeview on the left, clicked Resources » UrlLocalizationStrategies » SubFolderUrlLocalizationStrategy » Parameters

3-In Key includeSubfoderPrefixForDefaultLanguage, entered False

4-Saved my changes and restarted the application.

But it did not work. Now, pages are still showing default culture prefix in Page URLs

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pages are still showing default culture prefix in Page URLs" ? Do you mean the navigation widget still generates page urls with the default culture prefix? If so, do you use the built-in nav widget? mvc or webforms?

Comment: No I mean when I navigate pages from back end of sitefinity. It shows language prefix in page URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

navigate to Administration > Settings > Advanced > ContentView > Controls > FrontendPages > Views > FrontendPagesListView > View Modes > TreeTable > Columns > ViewColumn

There, under Client Template you will see something like this:

```
<a sys:href="{{ (PageLiveUrl) }}" target="_blank">View</a>
```

From what I see, this PageLiveUrl is resolved by not taking the includeSubfolderPrefixForDefaultLanguage param into account.
So, what you can do is to manually remove the language portion:

```
<a sys:href="{{ (PageLiveUrl).replace('/en/', '/') }}" target="_blank">View</a>
```

Save and refresh the page.